# What are the differences between $http.get and $http.post on local json files?

Tags: json, post, get

I am building a simple app which updates customer results via a local JSON file (data/customers.json). I have been testing a $get.http request which works absolutely fine on my local server:

```
 app.controller(“customersCtrl", function($scope, $http){
      $http.get(“data/customers.json")
        .success(function(data){
          $scope.recipients = data;
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data){
          alert("shit");
        });
```

I created a standard Jquery modal form #add-customer to input new customers to the JSON file via hg-model, for example:

```
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model=“customer.Name"/>    
           ...
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click=“addCustomer();">Add Customer</button>
```

And a basic addCustomer function:

```
$scope.addRecipient = function(){
          $http.post(“data/customers.json", $scope.customer)
            .then(function(){
              $("#add-customer").modal("hide");
              location.reload();
        });

}
```

The problem is that I am now getting a bizarre 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) In spite of the JSON file being clearly there (http://localhost:8000/data/customers.json).

Is there something that I am missing? Isn’t a local JSON file supposed to behave like a CRUD APi?

Comment: It's hard to tell why your server responds in a particular way when you only show us client side code.

Comment: Fair enough but in theory, shouldn't local JSON files behave in the same way for get and post on your local machine?

Comment: Not necessarily. 404ing is wrong, but throwing out a 405 when you make a POST request to a static file makes sense.

Comment: Damn... I am still in the dark. Would putting my JSON file live help you understand what is happening?

Comment: No, since (assuming the URL is correct) the problem is server configuration, not the content of the file. I don't understand why you would want to make a POST request to a static file anyway.

Comment: I just want to update the JSON contents as a test tool. Is this not the way to do it? I uploaded the JSON file and now I am getting the following error: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." How do I enable CORS on my server?